# Is there an equivalent to Mathematica's "usage" function?

Tags: sympy

In Mathematicy, one can define tags of a function such as

```
f::usage = "f[x] gives (x - 1)(x + 1)";
```

which can then be called like:

```
?f
```

Is there an equivalent in SymPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can “monkey patch” the docstring as follows:

```
import sympy
f = sympy.Function("f")
f.__doc__ = "A naked function without any special properties"
```

You can retrieve the docstring in the very same way, e.g., `print(f.__doc__)`. In iPython and similar, you can also use `f?` to obtain it (together with some other information).