# How to assign properties to symbols in SymPy and have them in the same domain?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, sympy

I want to extend the `Symbols` class in `SymPy` so that I can add a Boolean attribute.  I’m able to accomplish this for a single symbol (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228083/), and also someone else’s question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021227/)).  And the code to accomplish this is repeated below:

```
from sympy.core.symbol import Symbol
class State(Symbol):
    def __init__(self, name, boolean_attr):
        self.boolean_attr = boolean_attr
        super(State, self).__init__(name)
```

However, the problem with this solution is that when I am defining a polynomial, or some kind of expression involving more than one `State`, which is my extension of the `Symbol` class as you can see above, I need them all to be in the same domain when I evaluate it:

symbols defined separately cannot be evaluated numerically:

```
x=sympy.symbols('x')
y=sympy.symbols('y')
some_poly = Poly(x+y)
print some_poly.evalf(subs=dict(zip([sympy.symbols('x, y')],[1,4])))
>>> Poly(x + y, x, y, domain='ZZ')
```

symbols defined in the same domain *can* be evaluated numerically:

```
x, y = sympy.symbols('x, y')
some_poly = Poly(x+y)
print some_poly.evalf(subs=dict(zip(sympy.symbols('x,y'),[1,1])))
>>> 2.00000
```

**Here is my question**: How do I achieve this same behavior in my `class State`?    Ideally it would work as follows:

```
x=State('x', boolean_attr=True)
y=State('y', boolean_attr=False)
states_poly = Poly(x+y)
print states_poly.evalf(subs=dict(zip(States('x,y'),[1,1])))
>>> 2.00000
```

But that doesn’t work because `Sympy` interprets x and y as being in different domains.  How do I either:

- get `Sympy` to interpret `x` and `y` as being in the same domain 
  OR
- extend the `State` class to be able to define symbols in the same domain, e.g.:

  x, y =State('x, y', boolean_attr=[True, False])

How do I allow my polynomials defined using my extended class to be evaluated numerically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example you put `symbols` in a list so you didn't zip x and y with the values 1, 4:

```
>>> Poly(x+y).evalf(subs=dict(zip(sympy.symbols('x, y'),[1,4])))
5.00000000000000
```

You will get the desired result if you use the same State symbols that you defined

```
>>> x=State('x', boolean_attr=True)
... y=State('y', boolean_attr=False)
... states_poly = Poly(x+y)
... states_poly.evalf(subs=dict(zip((x,y),[1,1])))
2.00000000000000
```

(In your proposed syntax you used `States` which was undefined. Even if it did work, such a routine wouldn't have put True for one `boolean_attr` and False for the other and since Symbols match on attributes, the substitution would have failed.)

Comment: Ah, I can't believe it was that trivial!  Thank you @smichr.  The reason I had it wrapped in a list was because `zip(sympy.symbols('x'),[1])` doesn't work since `sympy.symbols('x')` is not iterable.  But for multiple symbols it doesn't matter.

Comment: As perhaps a follow-up question, Is there then no difference between initializing together versus initializing separately:  `x=sympy.symbols('x'),
y=sympy.symbols('y')`
and
`x, y = sympy.symbols('x, y')`
and my problems were just with using `zip` incorrectly.  Is that right?

Comment: However, as your answer post indicates, there *is* a difference between `states_poly.evalf(subs=dict(zip((x,y),[1,1])))` and `states_poly.evalf(subs=dict(zip(sympy.symbols('x,y'),[1,1])))`.

Comment: `symbols('x,')` will create `(x,)` instead of `x`. And when initializing several variables at once, they all are created with the same attributes.

Comment: But if you already have x and y defined with some special attributes then`symbols('x,y')` is not creating the same Symbols, it creates 2 new Symbols which have the same name but different attributes and are this distinct. And that is why the substitution failed for you.