# How to add arguments to a class that extends `Poly` class in sympy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, sympy

I am trying to create a class called `PolyExt` which is an extension of the `Poly` class in SymPy.  And, it has its own `__init__` method.  But the problem is that when it passes through the `__new__` method in the inherited `Poly` class, the extra arguments that I added to the `__init__` method get interpreted as part of the `*gens` argument.  Is there an elegant way around this?

Here is how to reproduce the error:

```
class PolyExt(Poly):

    def __init__(self, expression, symb1, symb2):
        self.symb1 = symb1
        self.symb2 = symb2
        super(PolyExt, self).__init__(expression)

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')

PolyExt(x+y, [y], [x])
```

And, the `Poly` class looks like the following:

```
class Poly(Expr):
    """Generic class for representing polynomial expressions."""

    __slots__ = ['rep', 'gens']

    is_commutative = True
    is_Poly = True

    def __new__(cls, rep, *gens, **args):
        """Create a new polynomial instance out of something useful. """
        opt = options.build_options(gens, args)
```

I tried using keyword arguments for `symb1`, and  `symb2` but again, the `__new__` method of the `Poly` class gets in the way, just try the code below

```
class PolyExt(Poly):

    def __init__(self, expression, **kwargs):
        self.symb1 = kwargs['symb1']
        self.symb2 = kwargs['symb2']
        super(PolyExt, self).__init__(expression)

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')

PolyExt(x+y, symb1=[y], symb2=[x])
```

What can I do to get around this?  Do I need to write my own `__new__` method to override the one in `class PolyExt`?  Or is it something else I’m missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `__new__` as well:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y

class PolyExt(Poly):

    def __new__(self, expression, symb1, symb2):
        obj = Poly.__new__(self, expression)
        obj.symb1 = symb1
        obj.symb2 = symb2
        return obj

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y')

p = PolyExt(x+y, [y], [x])
print(p.symb1)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have a follow-up question.  What determines whether I need to override the `__new__` method? I have a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333942/how-to-assign-properties-to-symbols-in-sympy-and-have-them-in-the-same-domain), in which I extended the `Symbol` class, but it did NOT require me to override the `__new__` method, even though the arguments are different.   `class Symbol` has `def __new__(cls, name, **assumptions)`, and my extended class (see the question) has an extra argument: `def __init__(self, name, costate)`.

Comment: `__new__` is called to *construct* an object and `__init__` is called later to initialise it. The argument you pass to `PolyExt(...)` are received first by `Poly.__new__` which will interpret them as `*gens` because that is its signature. Symbol doesn't expect args but it allows kwargs and in the other post you used your boolean_attr as a keyword argument. If you pass a positional argument it will raise.

Comment: Ah, excuse me for not realizing `*gens` was a positional argument!  Obviously that's key here.  thanks @OscarBenjamin.