# How to create two different sympy symbols with the same name

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021227/possible-to-add-descriptions-to-symbols-in-sympy) and came across some interesting behaviour:

```
from sympy import Symbol


class MySymbol(Symbol):

    def __new__(cls, symbol, description):

        obj = super().__new__(cls, symbol)
        obj.description = description
        return obj


symbolx = MySymbol('x', 100)
symbolx2 = MySymbol('x', 200)
symboly = MySymbol('y', 300)

print(symbolx.description)
print(symbolx2.description)
print(symboly.description)
```

returns:

```
200
200
300
```

Instead of the expected

```
100
200
300
```

My best guess is that `sympy` returns the same `Symbol` for a given name. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I don't understand how you would even use this. If I later had an expression `'x + y'` which `x` symbol should sympy use?

Comment: @CoryKramer I could go into the details, but it's a bit complex and I'm afraid it'll only make the question more confusing. I've really tried to boil it down the most basic problem. But in short, I intend to pass `symbolx + symboly` instead of `x + y`

Comment: The problem is that you're two symbols compare equal. The cache will return the same object. You could subclass Dummy instead of Symbol. I don't understand why you don't just give the symbols different names though and really I think that there are better ways of associating information with your symbols than using a subclass. Broadly I recommend taking a different approach to your overall problem.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin see my latest answer, is what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

Based on @OscarBenjamin s comment, using `Dummy` rather than `Symbol`:

```
from sympy import Dummy

class MySymbol(Dummy):

    def __new__(cls, symbol, description):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, symbol)
        obj.description = description
        return obj


symbolx = MySymbol('x', 100)
symbolx2 = MySymbol('x', 200)
symboly = MySymbol('y', 300)

print(symbolx.description)
print(symbolx2.description)
print(symboly.description)
```

Returns:

```
100
200
300
```

Comment: An advantage here over DescSymbol is that you retain ability to do manipulations: `symbolx + symbolx2 -> x + x`

Comment: @smichr With my answer you still can do all the operations using e.g. `symbolx.s + symbolx2.s` - and it actually performs the add, resulting in `2*x` compared to `_x + _x` using `MySymbol(Dummy)`

Comment: @matszwecja `performing the add` in this context is a bug, not a feature

Comment: @matszwecja, the nice thing about subclassing from Dummy is that you don't need to use the `s` attribute. This results in latex appearing as unevaluated Add without the need of creating an actual unevaluated Add.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a wrapper object instead of inheriting `Symbol`. This way you may store various data while still keeping all of the `sympy` functionality.

```
from sympy import Symbol, Add

symbols = []

class DescSymbol:
    def __init__(self, symbol, description):
        self.s = Symbol(symbol)
        self.description = description


symbolx = DescSymbol('x', 100)
symbolx2 = DescSymbol('x', 200)
symboly = DescSymbol('y', 300)

print(id(symbolx.s))
print(symbolx.description) # 100
print(id(symbolx2.s)) # same as symbolx.s
print(symbolx2.description) # 200
print(id(symboly.s)) # unique
print(symboly.description) # 300
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution I currently have is to append white space to the end of the symbol to ensure it's unique:

```
from sympy import Symbol

symbols = []

class MySymbol(Symbol):

    def __new__(cls, symbol, description):
        while symbol in symbols:
            symbol += ' '
        symbols.append(symbol)
        obj = super().__new__(cls, symbol)
        obj.description = description
        return obj


symbolx = MySymbol('x', 100)
symbolx2 = MySymbol('x', 200)
symboly = MySymbol('y', 300)

print(symbolx.description)
print(symbolx2.description)
print(symboly.description)
```

This returns:

```
100
200
300
```

I'll keep the question open in case anyone comes along with a more elegant answer

Comment: What's the point of using `x ` and not something like `z` then? You realise `x` and `x ` are different symbols that can't be added together?

Comment: @matszwecja spaces don't show up in LaTeX math enviornment. Like I've said; I've boiled the problem down to bare bones (because if I include all the details people won't read it)

Comment: Yeah but they will matter for all the Python preprocessing you will try to do before LaTeX will come into play.

Comment: @matszwecja I did some tests and I haven't been able to find any such effects

Comment: Try a simple example of `print(Add(Symbol('x'), Symbol('x')))` vs `print(Add(Symbol('x'), Symbol('x ')))` - one outputs `2*x` and the other `x + x `

Comment: @matszwecja I'm afraid we're now going outside of the scope of the question, I would be using it as `x = Symbol('x'); y = Symbol('x '); print(Add(x, y))` Thanks for your concern though!

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the same to what I wrote in the comments and it does not actually perform the add.

Comment: @matszwecja Exactly, that's the intended behaviour. It would be kind of weird to add two different values that happen to have the same symbol.

Comment: Why you'd want to have two different values use the same symbol is beyond me in that case.